# Stream on mongo replicat set return duplicate documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, duplicates, java-stream, database-replication

We have a mongo replicatSet of 3 instances
We have the following code with cause an issue because the stream return duplicate  documents

```
 Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(.....)    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("xxx").exists(true));
   query.cursorBatchSize(1000);
        Stream<XXX> streamOfXXX = StreamUtils
                .createStreamFromIterator(mongoTemplate.stream(query, YYY.class))
                .map(this::getXXX);
        PartitioningSpliterator.partition(streamOfXXX, 1000)
                .forEach(z -> feignClient.initYyy(bearer, z));

    }
```

Our issue  is that the feign client  receive duplicate  documents (almost 3 times )
We tested the same code with one instances  of mongo and we are getting the expected call number.

Is there any configuration  in mongo template to avoid this duplication  when working on replicat set?

Comment: What read concern are you using?

Comment: we didn't set any particular read concern, we suppose it user the default value locale as the read preference is primary by default

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly it was not the stream neither the spliterator but our API gateway witch reply the request 3 times after the timeout.

At least a good news , the stream is working fine